# Interact with an already running program

Tags: c++

I'm writing a console emulator in C++. I want to be able to "jump in" while it's running. Check out this simple example:

```
#include <iostream>

int main(){
    std::string input;
    std::cin >> input;
    std::cout << input;
}
```

I'd like to run this program on a server (locally), then connect to this server by SSH and somehow insert the input to the running program. I also want to be able to receive its output. The point here is, that I can't run more than one instance of the emulator. It has to run all the time and people need to be able to connect to it. Is it even possible? Are there any tutorials related to this topic?

Comment: OS-specific. If you can't spawn per-ssh-login subprocesses, you'd prolly need some piping and anotation mechanism

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz I forgot to mention that it will run on Linux OS.

Comment: @n.m. Well, that's the easiest way to go. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is more than one way to do that.  Consider the following:

1. Create a standard TCP/IP server (think HTTP server for example - this is exactly what one does - read in some strings as input, write out some strings as output).  A server can be accessed via SSH using "tunneling", which you can google.  You might need to write a client for it as well
2. Use a web server and create dynamic pages which will handle your data request/response.  There are many frameworks you can choose to implement this
3. Use IPC (inter process communication)

Answer (score 1):

what you want here is a command processor added to your program:
On a separate thread, listen to a linux socket for commands; it all boils down to reading the socket in your process an writing to it from wherever you want.

Please mind that reading data from the socket can be tricky and you don't want to get stuck waiting for data or take too much processor time waiting for data to arrive - but that is a different topic :)

I use this mechanism for loads of back-end processes and it has yet to fail me.